# How to make Angular recognize HTML inside a binding?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make Angular recognize  tags inside a bound text:

```
<p *ngFor="let explanation of explanations">{{explanation.htmlText}}</p>
```

This is how the explanation object looks like:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "htmlText": "This is a dummy text to test <a>links</a>. Looks like it doesn't work."
}
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can make it recognize the `<a>` tags and show an actual `<a>` element inside the `<p>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` because the traditional interpolation won't work,

```
<p *ngFor="let explanation of explanations" [innerHTML]="explanation.htmlText"></p>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use the sanitizer with the `innerHTML` attribute.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

sanitize(value: string) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.explanation.value);
}
```

```html
<span [innerHTML]="sanitize(explanation.htmlText)"></span>
```

Comment: If it is multiple object ? how you will do

Comment: This is basic coding, you should not ask that. But I edited my answer to fit your case, feel free to check it out.

Comment: Good, it's understandable

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre tag.

```
<p *ngFor="let explanation of explanations">
  <pre>
     {{explanation.htmlText}}
  </pre>
</p>
```